# React when checkbox checked filter data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

on games page if you are search a game, page is redirect to search result page. I want a filter on search result page. When I checked checkbox, data will be filtered.

json format is here

```
{"id": 26,
"title": "ebirth",
"sortName": "",
"isFullyOptimized": false,
"steamUrl": "",
"store": "",
"publisher": "",
"genres": ["Action", "Simulation"],
"status": "AVAILABLE"}
```

I have a aside menu component there is checkboxes. I want when I checked checkbox here I filtered by genres and status to my search results. Data returned from search results here

```
{gameIds.length > 0 && (
    <div className="search-result__content">
      <div className="search-result__title">
        <h2>Search Results</h2>
        <span>{data.filter(({ id }) => gameIds.includes(id)).length} results</span>
      </div>
      <div className="game-card__content">
        {data
          .filter(({ id }) => gameIds.includes(id))
          .map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <a key={i} href={item.steamUrl} className={item.steamUrl && "has-url" ? "has-url" : ""}>{item.title}</a>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
```

How can I do this?

Here is the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bardeen-pf1k0

Comment: Could you better summarize your question and also copy and paste the code you're seeking help with? Providing only links to your code is poor practice as links go dead over time and your question becomes useless.

Comment: @codemonkey can you take a look again?

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. When someone searched for something on this page: https://pf1k0.csb.app/ and then hits "Enter", you want the https://pf1k0.csb.app/SearchResult to pull up already prefiltered right?

Comment: @codemonkey yes, but also in search result page I have checkboxes. I want when I checked checkbox here data filtered by genres and status.